# Breeze using incorrect autoGeneratedKeyType in meta data parse

Tags: primary-key, identity, breeze

We're using BreezeJS for a project. It's a wonderful tool, thanks for creating it!

I have a table that has a two-column primary key. Also on this table is an identity column that is not part of the primary key.

In your client-side JS (as part of the parsing of the metadata), the function parseCsdlSimpleProperty sets the entityType's autoGeneratedKeyType to "Identity" after it parses the identity column, even though it is not part of the key:

```
var isPartOfKey = keyNamesOnServer != null && keyNamesOnServer.indexOf(csdlProperty.name) >= 0;
    if (parentType.autoGeneratedKeyType == AutoGeneratedKeyType.None) {
        if (isIdentityProperty(csdlProperty)) {
            parentType.autoGeneratedKeyType = AutoGeneratedKeyType.Identity;
        }
    }
```

This causes a problem for us after the entity has been saved back to the database. The entity that is returned after calling saveChanges() has an incorrect KeyMapping that causes a "Internal Error in key fixup - unable to locate entity" error.

I've changed it in my local copy to also check if this property is part of the primary key:

```
var isPartOfKey = keyNamesOnServer != null && keyNamesOnServer.indexOf(csdlProperty.name) >= 0;
    if (parentType.autoGeneratedKeyType == AutoGeneratedKeyType.None && isPartOfKey) {
        if (isIdentityProperty(csdlProperty)) {
            parentType.autoGeneratedKeyType = AutoGeneratedKeyType.Identity;
        }
    }
```

I think this is a valid fix as it is accepted practise to use an identity column outside of the primary key, but please tell me if I'm wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**: May 8, 2013 - This is now fixed in v 1.3.3 and available on the Breeze website.

---

We hadn't considered that an Identity column might not be the key. Haven't seen this before but it is reasonable.  Please add a request to the [Breeze User Voice](https://breezejs.uservoice.com/forums/173093-breeze-feature-suggestions) for this.  We take these requests very seriously. I will also investigate a temporary workaround, but this might take a few days.